# Regular expression for digits in a certain range

Tags: python, regex

So i am trying to write a regular expression that will accept any digits between 0 and 100. What I tried is \d+{0-100}. but that didn't work. I am not sure if the syntax is wrong or there is another problem since I am fairly new to re. Thanks for your help

Comment: should it instead be \d{0-100}

Comment: `\b(100|\d{1,2})\b` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQ5jM1/1)

Comment: Or to exclude negative numbers: `r'(?<!-)\b(\d{1,2}|100)\b'`

Answer (score 0):

Check this one 
\b(\d{1,2}|100)\b
This will match any number with at least 2 numbers or 100 only.

Comment: This leaves out numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: `{1,2}` could be good.

Comment: You are right, my bad.